# Parralax effect on scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have seen many tutorials about creating a parallax effect, however most of them seem to be with one image and a UITableView or using the accelerometer. I have failed to come accross a tutorial that shows how to do it using UIScrollView.

The effect I am looking for is seen in Yik Yak and Two Dots. Any tutorials/githubs around as I can't find them?

So looking for the objects to move acording to the scroll position.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved parallax in an UITableView with a single background image, but you might just loop through all your objects and use different factors depending how "deep" your view is.

This is just how it's done basically, but I'm pretty sure you'll be able to easily translate my code to your project:

```
// of cause, you have to have your view controller as delegate for the scroll view
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect backgroundImageFrame = [_backgroundImageView frame];
    backgroundImageFrame.origin.y -= (scrollView.contentOffset.y - _previousY) / 2.25;
    //     play around with different factors here to meet your needs here       ^^^^

    CGFloat scaledImageHeight = _backgroundImageView.image.size.height * _backgroundImageView.scaledImageSize.height;
    CGFloat relativeImageY = _backgroundImageView.superview.frame.size.height - backgroundImageFrame.origin.y;

    if ((scaledImageHeight - relativeImageY + 49) >= 0) {
    //    this is just a bit extra padding    ^^
        _previousY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        [_backgroundImageView setFrame:backgroundImageFrame];
    }
}
```